# How to uninstall leiningen which was installed through the script?

Tags: software-uninstall, jvm

I have installed leiningen using [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein) script. How can I uninstall it?

I tried this [SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363681/uninstall-reinstall-leiningenclojure-server-related-issues) but it says `self-install` is deprecated.

Comment: # Ensure this file is executable via `chmod a+x lein`, then place it # somewhere on your $PATH, like `~/bin`. The rest of Leiningen will be # installed upon first run into the `~/.lein/self-installs` directory. So **I guess** you should delete that directory.

Comment: `~/.lein/self-installs` ?

Comment: That Worked. You could write an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script has some helpful comments at the start:

> ```
> # Ensure this file is executable via `chmod a+x lein`, then place it
> # somewhere on your $PATH, like ~/bin. The rest of Leiningen will be
> # installed upon first run into the ~/.lein/self-installs directory.
> ```

So to uninstall it, in theory you only need remove that directory

```
rm -r ~/.lein
```

assuming you did not run the script as root.

If you might want to reinstall the program in the future, you can keep the script; since it's in a path location, typing `lein` would cause the script to be run again, reinstalling the software. If you don't want this to happen, delete the script itself (`rm ~/bin/lein` assuming that is the path to it) or remove execute permission from it (`chmod -x ~/bin/lein`).

Comment: I would like to point out that if that script isn't removed, running `lein` in terminal will result in redownloading of the `leiningen`

Comment: If you are removing this as you want to install a different version of lein (to fix issues with [2.8.2](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/2506#issuecomment-447257710) for example) then leave the script under ~/bin and change the line under `LEIN_VERSION=` to the version you need then run `lein` and `lein repl` to get up and running again

Comment: @8bitme great tip - you could post that as an answer I think...

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to remove Lein to change the version that you are using because you are running into an issue similar to the one described [here on GitHub](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/2506#issuecomment-447257710) then remove Lein as [mentioned by Zanna](https://askubuntu.com/a/907653/527764):

```
rm -r ~/.lein
```

Update the version of Lein to the one you need in the `lein` script (the one you downloaded from the lein site possibly under `~/bin/lein`):

```
export LEIN_VERSION="2.8.2"
```

Change this to the version you want (in my case changing this to 2.8.1 resolved [the issue](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/2506#issuecomment-447257710)).

Install Lein again by running:

```
lein
```

Confirm all is in order by trying to run the repl:

```
lein repl
```

If you get something similar to the following you have successfully installed Lein:

```
 nREPL server started on port 50634 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:50634
 REPL-y 0.3.7, nREPL 0.2.12
 Clojure 1.8.0
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_121-b13
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
 Results: Stored in vars *1, *2, *3, an exception in *e
user=>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Find where did you place this executable and delete it:

```bsh
$ which lein # returns /path/to/lein
$ sudo rm /path/to/lein
```

2) Remove lein cache/config folder

```
$ rm -Rf ~/.lein
```